# How would I match a string that may or may not span multiple lines?

Tags: python, regex

I have a document that when converted to text splits the phone number onto multiple lines like this:

```
(xxx)-xxx-
xxxx
```

For a variety of reasons related to my project I can't simply join the lines.

If I know the `phonenumber="(555)-555-5555"` how can I compile a regex so that if I run it over

`(555)-555-
5555`

it will match?

**EDIT

To help clarify my question here it is in a more abstract form.

```
test_string = "xxxx xx x xxxx"
text = """xxxx xx
x
xxxx"""
```

I need the test string to be found in the text.  Newlines can be anywhere in the text and characters that need to be escaped should be taken into consideration.

Comment: What patterns have you tried?

Comment: You could always just remove all whitespace by replacing `\s+` with nothing and then do whatever you need to do.

Comment: Those flag don't make a regex multiline by magic, sorry. I suggest reading their documentation, but in the end I think you won't be using them (MULTILINE just change `^$` anchors' behaviour, DOTALL just change `.`'s behaviour)

Comment: I'm not trying to match a general phone number pattern. I know the phone number going into it the problem so I need to match the string representation of the phonenumber across multiple lines.

Comment: I know exactly what you want. You need to write in what format are your phone numbers.

Comment: @S.Jovan The phone numbers are extracted from unstructured text so they don't necessarily follow any specific format.

Comment: So, the new line can appear anywhere in the text?

Comment: @S.Jovan Correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple workaround would be to replace all the `\n` characters in the document text before you search it:

```
pat = re.compile(r'\(\d{3}\)-\d{3}\d{4}')
numbers = pat.findall(text.replace('\n',''))

# ['(555)-555-5555']
```

If this cannot be done for any reasons, the obvious answer, though unsightly, would be to handle a newline character between each search character:

```
pat = re.compile(r'\(\n*5\n*5\n*5\n*\)\n*-\n*5\n*5\n*5\n*-\n*5\n*5\n*5\n*5')
```

If you needed to handle any format, you can pad the format like so:

```
phonenumber = '(555)-555-5555'
pat = re.compile('\n*'.join(['\\'+i if not i.isalnum() else i for i in phonenumber]))

# pat 
# re.compile(r'\(\n*5\n*5\n*5\n*\)\n*\-\n*5\n*5\n*5\n*\-\n*5\n*5\n*5\n*5', re.UNICODE)
```

Test case:

```
import random
def rndinsert(s):
    i = random.randrange(len(s)-1)
    return s[:i] + '\n' + s[i:]

for i in range(10):
    print(pat.findall(rndinsert('abc (555)-555-5555 def')))

# ['(555)-555-5555']
# ['(555)-5\n55-5555']
# ['(555)-5\n55-5555']
# ['(555)-555-5555']
# ['(555\n)-555-5555']
# ['(5\n55)-555-5555']
# ['(555)\n-555-5555']
# ['(555)-\n555-5555']
# ['(\n555)-555-5555']
# ['(555)-555-555\n5']
```

Comment: "For a variety of reasons related to my project I can't simply join the lines." I think this suggests OP can't use this solution

Comment: Missed that part, but this doesn't mutate the original data, so I'm not sure if that could work for OP's purpose.  If that has been considered and tossed aside, I will gladly remove my answer.

Comment: @Idlehands I don't need a phone number pattern.  The phone number IS the pattern.  I just need to be able to find it if it happens to be split on multiple lines.

Comment: Then the obvious answer although unsightly would be `re.compile(r'\(\n*5\n*5\n*5\n*\)\n*-\n*5\n*5\n*5\n*-\n*5\n*5\n*5\n*5')`

Comment: @Idlehands The phone numbers are extracted from unstructured text so they don't necessarily always follow this format.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for a possible `\n` existing in the string:

```
import re
nums = ["(555)-555-\n5555", "(555)-555-5555"]
new_nums = [i for i in nums if re.findall('\([\d\n]+\)[\n-][\d\n]+-[\d\n]+', i)]
```

Output:

```
['(555)-555-\n5555', '(555)-555-5555']
```

Comment: The newline can be anywhere in the string.

Comment: Would `\n` match `\r` with python's regex engine? Otherwise since the data's origin isn't stated I'd suggest `[\d\r\n]`and `[\r\n-]` to handle linux (`\n`), windows (`\r\n`) and old-school macOS (`\r`) standard linebreaks character sequences.

Comment: This answer appears to be a phone number pattern tailored to a specific phone number format.  It should be assumed that the phone number (in whatever format it may be) IS the pattern and it may or may not be split on multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ["(555)-555-\n5555", "(55\n5)-555-\n55\n55", "(555\n)-555-\n5555", "(555)-555-5555"]

input = '(555)-555-5555'
#add new lines to input string
input = re.sub(r'(?!^|$)', r'\\n*', input)
#escape brackets ()
input = re.sub(r'(?=[()])', r'\\',input)

r = re.compile(input)

match = filter(r.match, data)
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/XlPXK8)